# Ruby on Rails complaining "Unknown key params"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to call find with the :params key, using a method call that looks like this:

```
Product.find(:all, :params => { :name => "Test" })
```

Error:

```
ArgumentError: Unknown key(s): params
```

Calling `Product.find(:all)` works just fine, but when I try to pass anything in with the `:params` key it throws an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Rails 3.x try:

```
Product.where(:name => "Test")
```

If Rails 2.x try:

```
Product.find(:all, :conditions => { :name => "Test" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `:conditions => { ... }` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
Product.where(:name => "Test" )
```

I have never seen a find with a nested hash of parameters.  The key should map to your field in the database.